# Is it possible to add custom domain in Azure Api Management through Azure rest api or azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rest-api

We have an Azure API Management Service and we need to configure custom domain with SSL certificate and We are trying to automate the process of adding the custom domain in Api management. Is it possible to add custom domain through Azure rest api or azure cli?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use either the PowerShell module, [New-AzureRmApiManagementCustomHostnameConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/New-AzureRmApiManagementCustomHostnameConfiguration?view=azurermps-6.13.0#:%7E:text=New-AzureRmApiManagementCustomHostnameConfiguration), or the Management API, [Gateway Hostname Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/gateway-hostname-configuration#:%7E:text=Gateway%20Hostname%20Configuration).

Comment: the management api which you suggested is for gateway hostname configuration which is different from custom hostname configuration.